# Merge two files based on the starting of the line

Tags: perl

I want to merge two files into one using perl. Below are the sample files.

```
***FILE 1***
XDC123
XDC456
XDC678
BB987
BB654

*** FILE 2 ***
XDC876
XDC234
XDC789
BB456
BB678
```

And I want the merged file to look like:

```
***MERGED FILE***
XDC123
XDC456
XDC678
XDC876
XDC234
XDC789
BB987
BB654
BB456
BB678
```

For the above functionality I have written the below perl script snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = 'C:/File1';
my $file2 = 'C:/File2';
my $file3 = 'C:/File3';

open( FILEONE,   '<$file1' );
open( FILETWO,   '<$file2' );
open( FILETHREE, '>$file3' );

while (<FILEONE>) {
   if (/^XDC/) {
      print FILETHREE;
   }
   if (/^BB/) {
      last;
   }
}
while (<FILETWO>) {
   if (/^XDC/) {
      print FILETHREE;
   }
   if (/^BB/) {
      last;
   }
}
while (<FILEONE>) {
   if (/^BB/) {
      print FILETHREE;
   }
}
while (<FILETWO>) {
   if (/^BB/) {
      print FILETHREE;
   }
}
close($file1);
close($file2);
close($file3);
```

But the merged file that is generated from the above code looks like:

```
***FILE 3***
XDC123
XDC456
XDC678
XDC876
XDC234
XDC789
BB654
BB678
```

The first line that starts from BB is missed out from both the files. Any help on this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can't you just do this in unix with cat file* | sort

Comment: @EssexBoy, actually you can just do `sort file*` and if they are sorted inside each file you can even do `sort -m file*` to merge sort the files.

Comment: @CoderHat `>` this handle for write the content I don't know how do you reading it. ?

Comment: While you may inflict on yourself whatever hardships you like, please at least indent your code and .lay it out clearly if you are asking other people to read it.

Comment: That code doesn't create the output you say it does. The first thing that happens is that your two input files are emptied. Please show your real code if you want help.

Comment: A Perl on-liner alternative for the sort command above: `perl -e "print foreach sort <>" File1 File2`

Comment: Do you actually need the `foreach` there? `print` should work in a list context.

Comment: i just edited the sample i/p and o/p. The lines are not in an alphabetic order to use sort.

Comment: @CoderHat, you are going to have to explain what you are trying to achieve much more clearly.   At first you post something that looks like you want sorting help, now you're saying you want a merge that preserves order, while somehow taking into account the first few characters of the lines involved.  How many characters in the prefix need to match?  Does the order of the files provided matter?  How big are the files you are processing--can they fit in memory?  Unless you can describe *exactly* how the files are to be merged it will be impossible for anyone to write a program to do it.

Comment: @daotoad, both the files will contain around 1000 lines each. And I know that these lines will be started with XDC and BB alone followed by few numbers. I want to merge them in such a way that I have XDC lines from file1 first, XDC lines from file2 next, BB lines from file1 and BB lines from file2 irrespective of the numbers following them. I want to maintain this order.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you iterate each file to the end, but never 'rewind' for if you're wanting to start over.

So your `while ( <FILEONE> ) {` line *consumes* (and discards) the first line that matches `m/^BB/` - the `last` exits the "while" loop, but *only* after it's already read the line.

However that's assuming you get your `open` statements right, because:

```
open( FILEONE,   '>$file1' );
```

Actually empties it, it doesn't read from it. So I am assuming you've transposed your code, and introduced new errors whilst doing so.

As a style point - you should really use 3 argument open, with lexical filehandles.

So instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = 'C:/File1';
my $file2 = 'C:/File2';
my $file3 = 'C:/File3';

my @lines;
foreach my $file ( $file1, $file2 ) {
   open( my $input, '<', $file ) or die $!;
   push( @lines, <$input> );
   close($input);
}

open( my $output, '>', $file3 ) or die $!;
print {$output} sort @lines;
close($output)
```

(Although as noted in the comments - if that's *all* you want to do,  the unix `sort` utility is probably sufficient).

However, if you need to preserve the numeric ordering, whilst sorting on the alphabetical, you need a slightly different data structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = 'C:/File1';
my $file2 = 'C:/File2';
my $file3 = 'C:/File3';

my %lines; 
foreach my $file ( $file1, $file2 ) {
   open( my $input, '<', $file ) or die $!;
   while ( my $line = <$file> ) { 
       my ( $key ) = $line =~ m/^(\D+)/; 
       push %{$lines{$key}}, $line; 
   }
   close($input);
}

open( my $output, '>', $file3 ) or die $!;

foreach my $key ( sort keys %lines ) {
   print {$output} @{$lines{$key}};
}
close($output)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The merged file is not about sorting. I just want to merge based on the start of the line maintaining the order.

Comment: The second preserves the ordering for all but the leading non-numeric characters.